# user photo on comment if logged in

Tags: php, image, session, authentication

I am making a comment function on a design view page and I just have a single question about displaying a picture if a user is registered.

I want to display a users profile picture if he/she is logged in. What is the best way to do this?
Can I set an `<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1" />` and autofill the name input field on the comment form if the user is logged in, or what is the best approach to do this?

When a user log in the following fields a set in the login function:

```
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $row["user_id"];
$_SESSION["user_name"] = $row["name"];
$_SESSION["user_logged_in"] = 1;
```

When a comment are posted by are non-registered or non-logged-in user, a silhouette will be displayed instead of a normal picture.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply put if..else

To add name of user logged in you can simply store his/her name into $_SESSION['name'] and display it name input field of comment box and if you do not want to let them change a name you can disable input field. 
Follow the code given below :

```
if($_SESSION['user_logged_in']==1) {
//show the proper profile pic of user along with name in name input field.
     <img src="$path_to_profile_pic" height="anything" width="anything" />
     <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>" disabled="disabled" />
}else{
// show silhouette image along with name Anonymous. 
      <img src="$path_to_silhouette _pic" height="anything" width="anything" />
      <input type="text" name="name" value="anonymous" />
 }
```